# Increase page loading speed

Tags: windows-phone-7, panorama-control

In my app, I've a panorama-page which contains around 10 panorama items. Each panorama item has some path drawings, a list picker and few input fields.
The problem i'm facing is that whenver i navigate to this page the navigation is very slow due to lot of content to initialize. If i comment the

```
InitializeComponent();
```

the loading becomes fast.
I thought of adding the XAML content in code, but the problem is that i've to access the input fields by their name in code, so it didn't worked.
Any idea how i can speed up the navigation to the page.
Thanks..

Comment: "I thought of adding the XAML content in code, but the problem is that i've to access the input fields by their name in code, so it didn't worked." If you really feel like this will help, and I have my doubts unless you only initialized fields lazily, then you can simply make your _own_ instance variables with the expected names. Somewhat implied by that statement, you either need to lazily load components as they become necessary, load them in the background in multiple threads (only draw in UI thread), or optimize the existing field's initialization. It's hard to say without code.

Answer (score 3):

From the [UI Guide](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=183218):

> Use either a single color background
>   or an image that spans the entire
>   panorama. If you decide to use an
>   image, any UI image type that is
>   supported by Silverlight is
>   acceptable, but JPEGs are recommended,
>   as they generally have smaller file
>   sizes than other formats.
>
> You can use multiple images as a
>   background, but you should note that
>   only one image should be displayed at
>   any given time.
>
> Background images should be between
>   480 x 800 pixels and 1024 x 800 pixels
>   (width x height) to ensure good
>   performance, minimal load time, and no scaling.
>
> Consider hiding panorama sections
>   until they have content to display.

Also, 10 PanoramaItems seems like a lot since the recommended maximum is 4. You should either cut down on the number, or hide the content until it's required. Have a read of the best practice guide for Panoramas on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941107%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I think you could improve page performance by creating usercontrols for the specific panorama items, add an empty panorama control to your page (with only the headers) and as picypg suggests load these usercontrols when they are needed.

Another way could be that you load the first page and show this one already to the user. In the background you could start loading the other panorama items.

My suggested approach would be for the first one. Using the lazyloading principle.

Answer (score 1):

I woudl assume that your delays are due to the number of items on the page. This will lead to a very large object graph which will take a long time to create. I'd also expect it's using lots of memory and you have a very high fill rate which is slowing down the GPU.

Having input items/fields on PanoItems can cause UX issues if you're not careful.

That many panoItems could also cause potential navigation issues for the user.

Comment: @Amresh, using a pivot would delay loading of some items so could improve start up, but 10 items is more than you probably want to put in a pivot (recommended max is 7). Panorama and Pivot are intended for different purposes so a straight substitution is rarely a good idea though. Maybe rethink the design to move some functionality to other pages.